# Mailgun 499 Errors Occurring After Mail Appears To Be Delivered

Tags: mailgun

For some reason we are seeing 499 errors in the log that appear to be occurring after the email shows to be delivered.

We are trying to get to the bottom of what might be going on as we are seeing a significant number of 499 errors.

For example, what we have noticed in the log is that the timestamp shows a message was delivered at 2:39 p.m. with subsequent 499 errors being logged after 2:39 pm for the same message. It doesn't make sense to us based on the timestamp why the message would be delivered and then generate errors after delivery.

Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.